# Use Microsoft Scripting Control to evaluate 'If' expressions (via c#)

Tags: c#, .net, vbscript, expression

I have some c# code that uses the Microsoft Scripting Control to evaluate some expressions:

```
using MSScriptControl; // references msscript.ocx

ScriptControlClass sc = new ScriptControlClass();
sc.Language = "VBScript";
sc.AllowUI = true;

try
{
    Console.WriteLine(sc.Eval(txtEx.Text).ToString());
}
    catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

(txtEx is a simple text field)

Numerical expressions: "6+4", "cos(34)", "abs(-99)", "round(1.234, 2)" etc. are fine

Boolean expressions: "true or false", "1=2" are fine

But how can I evaluate a simple 'if'? I have tried "if(true, 2, 3)", "iif(true, 2, 3)", "if (true) then 2 else 3" and "if (true) then 2 else 3 endif"

Can anybody please help me to evaluate simple conditional expressions? Any help much appreciated!

RH

Comment: This question is very old.  You should accept one if it helped!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your IF-expression in a function

```
Function test
   if (true) then
      return true
   else
      return false
   end if
End function
```

Add the function to the control and then use Run

```
Result = ScriptControl.Run("Test")
```

(the code above is not tested, but something along that way should work)

Check out this link for some more info

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184740

Answer (score 3):

```
using MSScriptControl; // references msscript.ocx

ScriptControlClass sc = new ScriptControlClass();
sc.Language = "VBScript";
sc.AllowUI = true;

// VBScript engine doesn’t have IIf function
// Adding wraper IIF function to script control.
// This IIF function will work just as VB6 IIf function.
sc.AddCode(@"Function IIF(Expression,TruePart,FalsePart)
                If Expression Then
                    IIF=TruePart
                Else
                    IIF=FalsePart
                End IF
            End Function");
try
{
    //define x,y variable with value
    sc.AddCode(@"x=5
                y=6");
    //test our IIF 
    Console.WriteLine(sc.Eval("IIF(x>y,x,y)").ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the expression evaluation engine that is part of Windows Workflow Foundation. Both the evaluator and the designer for it can be used separately from WF.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (true) then return 2 else return 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips! After a bit more experimenting, based on Brummo's help, this seems to work:

txtEx contains this text:

```
function test
  if (1=1) then 
    test = true
  else 
    test = false
  end if
end function
```

then

sc.AddCode(txtEx.Text);

and

```
object[] myParams = { };
Console.WriteLine(sc.Run("Test", ref myParams).ToString());
```

This isn't ideal, since I really wanted to evaluate an expression, without building, loading and evaluating a function. (I am surprised IIF doesn't work for simple one line if evaluation).